# AngularJs: How to start animation on value change (ng-scope)

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, animation

Let's say I have a template:

```
<div ng-controller="ValueCtrl">
<dl>
  <dt>Points</dt>
  <dd>{{ points }}</dd>
</dl>
</div>
```

and a controller:

```
app.controller('ValueCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.points = 100;
  $scope.$on('points:changed', function(newPoints) {
    $scope.points = newPoints;
  });
});
```

In my app I use animate.css from http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/.

I would like to have `points` value change animated. While I could add `animated pulse` CSS classes to the element via Javascript, I don't want to manipulate the DOM directly from the controller.

Is there a simple way I can detect a change through CSS? When using `ng-repeat` or `ng-show` etc. I can detect those by using CSS classes (like `ng-enter`, `ng-leave` etc). Is there a way to detect similar events for elements that are bound to the scope?

Answer (score 0):

The way to go is to use [`ng-class`](https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass) to make the class conditional on a scope variable (I'll use `$scope.changed`, a boolean).

**HTML**

```
<dl>
  <dt>Points</dt>
  <dd ng-class="{'animated bounce' : changed}">{{ points }}</dd>
</dl>
```

Since the `animate.css` lib cannot reset the `$scope.changed` signal variable, we have to do this after a certain time, so subsequent changes are able to trigger an animation.

**Javascript**

```
$scope.$on('points:changed', function(event, newPoints) {
    $scope.points = newPoints.points;
    $scope.changed = true;
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.changed = false;
    }, 1000);
  });
```

I have created a complete example as [a JSBin here](https://jsbin.com/sudilekeza/edit?html,js,output).